# How to remove loose letters from a text field on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following datadrame:

```
  import pandas as pd
  df_Msg = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3], 
               'Sentence': ['I like fictions', 'Thank s you', 'I need to by a new book']})

  print(df_Msg)
```

output:

```
Id   Sentence
1    I like fictions
2    Thank s you
3    I need to by a new book
```

I would like to remove all letters of the alphabet that appear alone. In this specific case, I need to remove the letters: I, s and a.
To do this I used replace() as follows:

```
df_Msg['Sentence'] = df_Msg['Sentence'].replace('I', '', regex=True)
df_Msg['Sentence'] = df_Msg['Sentence'].replace('s', '', regex=True)
df_Msg['Sentence'] = df_Msg['Sentence'].replace('a', '', regex=True)
```

The output:

```
Id  Sentence
1   like fiction
2   Thnk you
3   need to by new book
```

However, I would like the output to be:

```
Id   Sentence
1    like fictions
2    Thank you
3    need to by new book
```

Thank you

Comment: Simple job for a regex substitution although the challenge would be if you are very precise about what should be done concerning the surrounding whitespace in the cases where it is at the start, middle, or end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use a word boundary:

```
print(df_Msg["Sentence"].str.replace(r"\b[A-Za-z]\b\s?", ""))

0          like fictions
1              Thank you
2    need to by new book
Name: Sentence, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the complication of surrounding white-space for back-to-back single character words, split, remove words that are 1 character long and then join back.

```
df_Msg = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                      'Sentence': ['I like fictions', 'Thank s you', 'I need to by a new book', 
                                   'a b foo b b bar baz b c']})

s = df_Msg['Sentence'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
df_Msg['sentence'] = s[s.str.len().gt(1)].groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

---

```
   Id                 Sentence             sentence
0   1          I like fictions        like fictions
1   2              Thank s you            Thank you
2   3  I need to by a new book  need to by new book
3   4  a b foo b b bar baz b c          foo bar baz
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
import pandas as pd
df_Msg = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'Sentence': ['I like fictions', 'Thank s you', 'I need to by a new book']})

for i in range(len(df_Msg['Sentence'])):
   lst = df_Msg['Sentence'][i].split()
   for item in lst:
        if len(item) == 1 and item == 'I' or item == 's' or item == 'a':
            lst.remove(item)
        elif item[-1] == 's':
            lst.remove(item)
            item = item.replace('s','')
            lst.append(item)
   sentence = " ".join(lst)
   df_Msg['Sentence'][i] = sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apply method in Sentence column

```
df_Msg['Sentence'] = df_Msg.Sentence.apply(lambda x :" ".join([i for i in x.split() if len(i)>1]))
```